# How to stop audio when it is playing in another player parallely in Cordova Media Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-audio, cordova-plugins, android-audiomanager

I have an audio player in my app which was done using Ionic framework [Cordova Media Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media).

I want it to get stopped once another app player plays media.

I want only one audio player to be active at a time, does anybody have any clue on how to do this?

Comment: Small text correction in my question. please follow this comments:                       

 I want to stop when another player play media. Mobile have to play one audio at a time. How to do it?

Comment: Check the status of your media object as if(self.media){
        self.media.stop();
        self.media.release(); /

Comment: Make question even clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me, Check It

```
 var filedirPath = $ionicPlatform.is('android') ?  '/android_asset/www/app/audio' : 'audio';

var fileName = filedirPath + "/BlossominyourSmile.mp3";
 var media = new Media(self.fileName, function(){
          console.log("Silence played succssfully");
          // self.resetPlay();
        }, function(err){
      });
 media.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : true, numberOfLoops: 0});
```

Media Object will be created with some default methods as media.pause, media.resume, media.stop
check the status and you use the methods as

```
if(self.media){ self.media.stop(); self.media.release();}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anil kumar . Shall I know about what cordova plugin have used. I have already tried the above mentioned methods. I want whenever I play the sound(song) in my app, it should automatically stop the background player(audio service) and it should start playing the sound from my app.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Ionic 2` with [cordova-plugin-nativeaudio](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)

I preload all the files I need in the `constructor`, example for a single file

```
    platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.preloadTracks()
        });

        preloadTracks(list) {
          var path = this.keypadSounds.getAssetsPath();        
          list.forEach((el) => this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex(el, `${path}/${el}.mp3`, 1, 1, 0).then(
            () => {}, 
            (error) => {})
        );
    }
```

Then I can stop it with
`this.nativeAudio.stop(el);` wherever I need